# how to solve libdbus-1-3 (= 1.12.2-1ubuntu1.1) but 1.10.6-1ubuntu3.4 is installed

Tags: 18.04, software-installation, upgrade, updates

I'm trying to install ST-Link v2, but i ran into a error.

http://fab.cba.mit.edu/classes/863.13/tutorials/EmbeddedProgramming/stm32.html

this error seams to affect more issues, like the Ubuntu Software center.
nor can i install:

```
sudo apt-get install libusb-1.0-0-dev
sudo apt install git
```

i tried the usual stuff:

```
sudo apt-get -y update && sudo apt-get -y upgrade && sudo apt-get -y autoremove
```

aswel the recommended:

```
apt-get -f install
```

but nothing seams to work out.

```
    The following packages have unmet dependencies:

libdbus-1-dev: Depends: libdbus-1-3 (= 1.12.2-1ubuntu1.1) but 1.10.6-1ubuntu3.4 is installed
libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev: Depends: libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 (= 2.36.11-2) but 2.36.11-2 is installed
                      Depends: libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.48.0) but 2.48.2-0ubuntu4.4 is installed
                      Depends: gir1.2-gdkpixbuf-2.0 (= 2.36.11-2) but 2.32.2-1ubuntu1.6 is installed
                      Depends: libglib2.0-dev (>= 2.37.6) but 2.56.4-0ubuntu0.18.04.4 is installed
                      Depends: libpng-dev (>= 1.6) but it is not installed
                      Depends: libpng-dev (< 1.7) but it is not installed
libglib2.0-bin: Depends: libglib2.0-0 (= 2.56.4-0ubuntu0.18.04.4) but 2.48.2-0ubuntu4.4 is installed
libglib2.0-dev: Depends: libglib2.0-0 (= 2.56.4-0ubuntu0.18.04.4) but 2.48.2-0ubuntu4.4 is installed
                Depends: libglib2.0-bin (= 2.56.4-0ubuntu0.18.04.4) but 2.56.4-0ubuntu0.18.04.4 is installed
                Depends: libglib2.0-dev-bin (= 2.56.4-0ubuntu0.18.04.4) but 2.56.4-0ubuntu0.18.04.4 is installed
                Depends: libpcre3-dev (>= 1:8.31) but 2:8.39-9 is installed
libproxy1-plugin-gsettings: Depends: libc6 (>= 2.15) but 2.27-3ubuntu1 is installed
                            Depends: libgcc1 (>= 1:3.0) but 1:8.3.0-6ubuntu1~18.04.1 is installed
                            Depends: libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.45.3) but 2.48.2-0ubuntu4.4 is installed
                            Depends: libproxy1v5 (= 0.4.15-1) but 0.4.11-5ubuntu1 is installed
                            Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 5.2) but 8.3.0-6ubuntu1~18.04.1 is installed
python3-distutils: python3-lib2to3: systemd: Depends: libaudit1 (>= 1:2.2.1) but 1:2.8.2-1ubuntu1 is installed
         Depends: libcap2 (>= 1:2.10) but 1:2.24-12 is installed
         Depends: libcryptsetup4 (>= 2:1.4.3) but 2:1.6.6-5ubuntu2.1 is installed
         Depends: libsystemd0 (= 229-4ubuntu21.22) but 237-3ubuntu10.29 is installed
udev: Depends: libudev1 (= 229-4ubuntu21.22) but 237-3ubuntu10.29 is installed
```

thnx in advance

Comment: I know nothing about any of the packages you are trying to use, but the PPA in your instructions contains the note "*As previously announced all new binary and source packages will not be released on Launchpad henceforth, they can be found on:..*" so possibly you're following old un-maintained instructions (from 2013 so would apply 14.04).

Comment: i'm fairly new to Ubuntu, what is PPA? .. and where is this note?

Comment: The instructions make reference to https://launchpad.net/gcc-arm-embedded.  PPA = *3rd party* personal package archive (see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu for more info, 3.3 on adding PPAs).  The PPA I mention is the first line of installing toolchain (would be missed by those that copy/paste - I think about commands and the add-apt-repository would make me instantly look at PPA as it's 3rd party; security is your responsibility and I'd want to ensure maintained or trustworthy... etc)   *I also looked at date bottom right; in Ubuntu wiki etc last edit/date is there too*

Comment: i see now what you mean, but i'm currently not beabled to install anything.

the Ubuntu error report / reports a problem and i have to update a whole bunch of stuff and it doesn't allow me to copy it.

software and Updates crashes after i try to open it.
i orginally came from 14.04 witch installed some years ago and recently started using Ubunto again, a month ago i upgraded via command to 18.04.

Comment: The use of -y in your pastes implies to me you've forced prior commands without consideration of consequence, and thus your problem is the -y to force.. 
 The command `sudo apt-get install libusb-1.0-0-dev` requires only 1 package to be installed (https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/libusb-1.0-0-dev) which is not in your list so errors pre-date that command, ie. prior commands you 'forced' with '-y' that need reversing. Your errors are used caused and your question is incomplete (the only error possible from the command I've used in this comment would be related to libusb-1.0-0 (= 2:1.0.21-2)

Comment: well, yesterday i tried to installed Qucs "again" and it also failed.
so now i'm not sure where things might have gone wrong and how to reverse.

Comment: Your `history` & `/var/log/apt/history.log` will show your commands & errors you got that you've ignored. The number of issues and what's impacted just grow until addressed (stopping future upgrades/installs). My last comment was intended as explanation (ie. the command `apt-get install libusb-1.0-0-dev` would only have produced messages relating to clashes with libusb-1.0-0 of wrong versions - any other messages provided related to prior ignored messages created by forcing (ie. use of '-y').  You need to fix prior command errors  .. and this site doesn't allow for hand-holding via comments..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100267/discussion-between-naturaldemon-and-guiverc).